# Looking for a good free web usage monitor / proxy

Tags: proxy

I have just taken over responsibility for a small company who's network is a mess. 
No IT policy, no security etc etc.

One of my first requirements is to crack down on internet usage - So I'm looking for a good, preferably free system to enable me to track internet usage, block sites etc on a user-by-user basis (they are using Active Directory) with aprox 50 users.

I have spare hardware, so a dedicated server is available.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for a `web proxy` with `Access control list`

Squid + [active directory authentication](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory) + [sarg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sarg/)

Depending how much you are familiar to unix/Linux you can setup your own system from your favourite distro or install a prebuilt [firewall distro](https://distrowatch.com/search-mobile.php?ostype=All&category=Firewall&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=All&netinstall=All&language=All&status=Active#simple)

Answer (score 2):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) is a Windows-based proxy that may be helpful in this case.  It has a free license which handles up to 10 concurrently-connected clients. It will log requests, and allow you to block them per user.

If you want AD-integrated auth you would need to pay for a license however.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the author of WinGate